# How to make diff between two directories of a repo, then save the diff as a commit

Tags: git, moodle, git-commit, git-diff

How can I make a diff between two directories of a repository, then save this diff as a commit?

EDIT1:
Use case: There is a software named Moodle, which is hardly module based. Each feature is in a different directory.
I need to keep custom changes of each feature I've done and when the official software is released, I want to integrate my changes to the new release.

EDIT2:
I have an original release tagged with v2.7.0. I made custom changes to 30-40 directories. Now I have a commit with my all changes compared to the release v2.7.0. 
It is too much work to do the merge & conflict solving to release v3.2.0 in one step.
So I would split the changes into directories (features). Then, when I rebase changes over v3.2.0, I can rebase the feature/directory changes one by one. 
This is the job I would like to do now.

I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: If the number and names of files in each directory are not the same, your request doesn't make sense.  If you just want one directory to look like the other, why not just checkout all the files of interest?

Comment: Even _if_ the number and names of files in each directory are the same this doesn't make sense. What possible use could it be to diff the directories and then "save the diff as a commit"? What does that even mean?

Comment: @Chris It doesn't make sense because applying that diff to the directory behind the other one would just yield two identical directories.  I also sense some confusion about how Git works here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I'm on your side here. There are several ways in which this question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Added EDIT1 and EDIT2.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a bit rare and odd in Git. The diff is possible. Technically Git uses a `tree` object to describe a tracked directory. There are a number of tree-ish references in Git, one of which is `ref:directory`. And `git-diff` can compare any two random tracked folders(even not of the same repo). Assuming the repo has tracked two folders, `foo/` and `bar/`. Now it's on the branch `master`. The diff of foo and bar can be made through `git diff master:foo master:bar` , or `git diff master:bar master:foo` depending on your demand. The diff can be saved as a patch and the patch can be applied partially or fully. If the patch is successfully applied, you can then add and commit the changes.

Comment: Added EDIT1 and EDIT2.